# Ruby equivalent to Java's BigDecimal.setScale(6, Round_half_up)

Tags: java, ruby

Does ruby have any inbuilt function equivalent to Java's  BigDecimal.setScale(6, Round_half_up) ? I need to take 6 decimal values from a float number and round it based on the 7 value after the decimal.

Comment: Thank you All for answering to my question ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for [Float#round](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Float.html#method-i-round) which takes two arguments: a number of decimal digits and the `half` keyword specifying direction (rounding up is the default).

```
1.23456789.round(6, half: :up)
=> 1.234568
```

Prior to Ruby 2.4 you could not specify the rounding direction - it would always round up. [Heroku's "Ruby 2.4 Released: Faster Hashes, Unified Integers and Better Rounding"](https://blog.heroku.com/ruby-2-4-features-hashes-integers-rounding#proposed-rounding-changes) covers the change in some more detail.

[BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) helps you to perform these calculations more accurately (i.e. avoiding floating point arithmetic errors). Again, rounding up is the default but it can be explicitly specified:

```
big_decimal = BigDecimal("1.23456789")
big_decimal.round(6, BigDecimal::ROUND_HALF_UP).to_f
=> 1.234568
```

Comment: There is a problem: java BigDecimal has EXACT values, in Ruby Float has generally know features / problem with precision, conversion between internal for and characters etc...

Comment: @JacekCz Ruby has `BigDecimal` too just like Java has `float` and every language suffers with floating point precision. Sidenote: the above answer is only valid in Ruby >= 2.4

Comment: Very valid, thanks! I've edited the answer to include these points with examples.